# Why is a member not getting zero-initialized in this example?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization

This is specifically regarding C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A(){}
    int i;
};
struct B : public A {
    int j;
};
int main() {
    B b = {};
    std::cout << b.i << b.j << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with g++ 8.2.1:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -Wuninitialized -O2 a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:25:25: warning: ‘b.B::<anonymous>.A::i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl
```

gcc is detecting `b.i` as uninitialized, but I would  think it should be getting zero-initialized along with `b.j`.

What I *believe* is happening (C++11 specifically, from the ISO/IEC working draft N3337, emphasis mine):

- `B` is not an aggregate because it has a base class. Public base classes were only allowed in aggregates in C++17.
- `A` is not an aggregate because it has a user-provided constructor

Section 8.5.1

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with **no user-provided constructors** (12.1), no brace-or-equal initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

- `b` is getting list initialized with an empty braced-init-list

Section 8.5.4

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>   — **If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized**.
>   — Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).

- This means `b` gets value-initialized
- `B` has an implicitly-defined default constructor, so `b` value-initialization invokes zero-initialization
- `b.B::A` gets zero-initialized, which zero-initalizes `b.B::A.i`, and then `b.B::j` gets zero-initialized.

Section 8.5

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>   ...
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, **each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized** and padding is initialized to zero bits;

...

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>   default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>   — **if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>   is zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>   called.

However, it looks like gcc is saying only `b.B::j` is going to get zero-initialized. Why is this?

One reason I can think of is if `B` is being treated as an aggregate, which would initialize `b.B::A` with an empty list.
`B` is certainly not an aggregate, though, because gcc rightly errors if we try to use aggregate initialization.

```
// ... as in the above example
int main() {
    B b = {A{}, 1};
    std::cout << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with C++11

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -Wuninitialized -O2 a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:10:18: error: could not convert ‘{A(), 1}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘B’
     B b = {A{}, 1};
```

Compiling with C++17

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic-errors -Wuninitialized -O2 a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:11:25: warning: ‘b.B::<anonymous>.A::i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl;
```

And we can see that `b.i` is uninitialized because `B` is an aggregate, and `b.B::A` is getting initialized by an expression that itself leaves `A::i` uninitialized.

So it's not an aggregate. Another reason is if `b.B::j` is getting zero-initialized, and `b.B::A` is getting value-initialized, but I don't see that anywhere in the specs.

The last reason is if an older version of the standard was getting invoked.
From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> 2) if T is a non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   (until C++11)

In this case, both `b.B::i` and `b.B::A` would be value-initialized, which would cause this behavior, but that is marked as *"(until C++11)"*.

Comment: You defined a constructor and the compiler is using it.

`A() = default;`

Or just don't define it at all since you don't have any user-defined types members.

Comment: @Koori `b` is getting zero-initialized. This should zero-initialize all bases and non-static members. Unless it's not getting zero-initialized...

Comment: Problem is that the compiler is not "zero-initializing" the bases, it is actually calling the default constructor of it.

Since you defined a constructor for A, B's constructor will call that A constructor you defined.

You just have to simply remove `A(){}` or change it to `A() = default;`

Comment: @MikeLui If you want an answer that has references from the standard to back them up you should add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: Compiler bug. (But it is probably unnecessarily brittle to rely on this anyway.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd also go with compiler bug.

- I think we can all agree that `b` gets value-initialized (8.5.4)
- Using

  > value-initialize an object of type T means:
  >   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type **without** a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized **and**, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.

  So what should happen is **first** zero-initialization, **then** default ctors may be called
- And with the definition:

  > To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
  >   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and **each base-class subobject is zero-initialized** and padding is initialized to zero bits;

Hence the following should happen:

1. Fill `sizeof(B)` with zeroes
2. Call constructor of subobject `A` which does nothing.

I assume this is a bug in the optimization. Compare the output of `-O0` to `-O1`: https://godbolt.org/z/20QBoR. Without optimization the behaviour is correct. Clang on the other hand is correct in both: https://godbolt.org/z/7uhlIi

This "bug" is still present with newer standard flags in GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/ivkE5K

However I assume in C++20 `B` is an "aggregate" so the behavior becomes standard.

Answer (score 8):

For any class, if there is a single user-defined constructor it must be used, and `A(){}` does not initialise `i`.

Comment: There's always a constructor. Depending on how it is defined (user-provided or not), the object may get zero-initialized beforehand. I believe in this situation there should be zero-initialization. The presence of a constructor in a base class does not preclude zero-initialization, as I have seen it defined in the standard. C++11 working draft 8.5:  *"To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means: ... if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;"*

Comment: [The section on zero initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#6) seems to disagree with this.

Comment: Added "user-defined".

Answer (score -1):

Nothing is initializing `i`. It doesn't happen automatically. You need to either initialize it in-class or in the initialization list of the class constructor. Or remove your non-trivial/user-defined constructor (or `= default` it, which makes it trivial).

The compiler is using the constructor you provided and that ctor does *not* initialize `i`.

Comment: Or remove the user-defined default constructor.